# How to get a Corsair gaming keyboard to act like a standard USB HID keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, openbsd

I have a Corsair Strafe RGB keyboard which has caused a number of boot and suspend/resume issues on Linux due to some kind of USB error. On recent kernels, the issue has been mostly fixed, but it still hangs the boot by about ten seconds every time.

I went to install OpenBSD earlier today and encountered another eerily familiar boot hang when it was initializing USB devices. By the time it timed out, the OS printed a something along the lines of “disabling usb6” (it scrolled by too fast to read or take a picture of, though). The keyboard backlight then turned off and I could not input text into the installer.

After a bit of research that I dug back up again, I found that it can, in fact be fixed in software (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1678477), but this leads me to believe that it is a hardware issue since it requires this patch.

Since the issue affects multiple Linux distros, kernels, and even OpenBSD, I think that there’s something wrong with the keyboard firmware or hardware.

Is there something I can use to solve the issue in some way? I was thinking that I could try jerry-rigging a USB-PS2-USB setup, but am unsure if it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason that a variety of standards-complaint kernels fail to initialize the keyboard is due to how the backlight pulls more power than the USB 2.0 specification is intended to handle.

The issue is solved when using a powered USB hub. No PS/2 adapter setup required.